# Dragon Seekers quest broken?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

After completing the Companions quest line, I went on to do the side missions afterwards. I started with Farkas on the quest Dragon Seekers.

Our target was the dragon at Bonestrewn Crest. I fast traveled to the location because I had been there already and killed the dragon before. When we got there the dragon was hovering about and Farkas and I easily killed it. However, the marker lead about a hundred yards from the Word Wall and killed the dragon did not satisfy the quest.

I wouldn't mind ditching this quest if Farkas would stop following. I've tried many things.
- Waiting weeks and killing the other dragons that spawn.
- Killing Farkas.
- Marring Farkas. (Gay)
- Getting others to kill Farkas.

My last save was after I killed the dragon too. Also I am on the Xbox. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This doesn't solve it, but the [wikia page for this quest](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Seekers) has this bug listed: If sent to kill a dragon that is also marked as a current bounty quest, the bounty quest will override the "Dragon Seekers" quest and will not be completable, leaving Farkas or Vilkas as a permanent follower with no other dialogue options aside from training.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is an Xbox 360 issue, console commands, the game-engine based code that runs the game and it's scripts, cannot be used. They are for PC only. And, since Skyrim on the 360 is riddled with bugs and glitches, with only some minor in-game workarounds, the best option is to load a previous save.

You have made it clear in your question that you do not have a save previous to this issue. Let it serve as a lesson to make multiple saves over time; it helps in case things go sour.

Comment: I think you can transfer a saved game to PC, if you have a Windows copy of Skyrim, and then fix the game in the console, and transfer it back to Xbox.

Comment: @amaranth I suppose that is true, but it requires some third party software, and a copy of Skyrim on PC, which OP hasn't stated that they own. Also question is almost 4 years old at this point, but still a valid suggestions. :)